# ATI graphics card overriding onboard Intel graphics

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I have an ATI graphics card with an AGP connection and a DVI port, and an Intel graphics processor on the motherboard with a VGA port. I have two monitors.

When the graphics card is unplugged, I get this from lspci:

> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 10)
>
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 10)

When it is attached, I get this:

> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 10)
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RV380 [Radeon X600 (PCIE)]
>
> 01:00.1 Display controller: ATI Technologies Inc RV380 [Radeon X600]

Note the absence of 00:02.0 - this is apparently causing the VGA monitor to say "No Signal" and the only the DVI display to show up in the list.

I checked for problems in xorg.conf... there isn't one. I have no idea how to build one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can recommend is: Check your BIOS.

If it's not showing up in `lspci`, the problem is way above X's jurisdiction. It *could* be kernel related but logically speaking, this sounds like a power-saving "feature" on the motherboard.

Check through the settings in the BIOS and see if you can see anything to do with the onboard graphics. If it's set to something fuzzy like "Auto", change it to something more assertive like "Enabled".

Or buy a new card with both outputs on the one card. As AGP is dying out, they're quire easy to pick up second hand, dirt cheap. Leave it much longer and they'll start going up as they get rarer.

Comment: If a card has two outputs, I can use both at the same time, right? I checked for bios stuff, the only graphics options were "PCI" and "PCI Express". And there was something about allowing/disallowing the card to request an IRQ, that did nothing.

Comment: "I can use both at the same time, right?" That is what I have done for a very long time. I've only done it with nvidia cards in Linux though.

Comment: Oh and if you have the option of a PCI Express graphics card (ie there's a slot on the board) you should be able to find an even cheaper graphics card. You can get a *new* Nvidia 8400GS for just over £20 and that has VGA+DVI+HDMI connectors (though you can only use two at once). Bargain.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue please try disabling secure boot in case of dual boot or changing the drivers to go with xord ones.
Hope it helps:
Ref: [Not detected second screen after update, Quadro RTX 3000 Mobile , Lenovo hinkpad p15 g1, Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332114/not-detected-second-screen-after-update-quadro-rtx-3000-mobile-lenovo-hinkpad?noredirect=1&lq=1)