# nvidia drivers not working on ubuntu 20.04 with Nvidia quantum rtx 4000

Tags: drivers, nvidia, tensorflow

I have an issue using my nvidia gpu with python tensorflow-gpu in ubunti 20.04 it is not detected. Please help me do some diagnostics if you have some idea

In windows this works fine.
What I tried :

- Changin hybrid to discrete settings makes ubuntu not having any display.
- I tried changind the versions of gpu proprietart drivers available but without luck (tried all without restarting and only 460 and 450 with restarting i wil ltry the rest and report here)

Disclaimer the nvidia card originally cause d me to be unable to use my external monitort this can be solved using the open source drivers:
[Not detected second screen after update, Quadro RTX 3000 Mobile , Lenovo hinkpad p15 g1, Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332114/not-detected-second-screen-after-update-quadro-rtx-3000-mobile-lenovo-hinkpad)

Comment: Have you disabled Secure Boot?

Comment: Hello and thank you for the comment,  is it influencing you think?

Comment: I didn't disable it, I only played modifying discrete and hybrid graphics.

Comment: Secure Boot prevents loading unsigned drivers like the ones from Nvidia, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as usual, is having Secure Boot enabled in UEFI and unsigned drivers (Nvidia's).

Either disable Secure Boot in UEFI (easy) or use mokutil to enable "trust" for the Nvidia's driver modules (not easy).

Comment: Thanks will give a try

Comment: It worked thank you so much!